# How to subset from a list?

Tags: r, list, subset, lapply

I want a subset of my list, but in the list are still the entries on which the subset does not apply.
In my list should be only the entries that fit the subset function.
How can I solve this problem?
I made an example with **flights**
Thank you!

**Edit:**

```
install.packages("nycflights13")
library(nycflights13)
library(plyr)
```

```
list_flights<-dlply(flights,"carrier")

subset_list<-lapply(list_flights, function(x) subset(x,dest == "BWI" & origin == "EWR"))
```

Comment: Please specify all non-base packages with `library()` calls. Also, `flights` is not available in base R. Please define its source with `dput` or `library` its origins.

Comment: I would do the filtering on the dataframe and split it up afterwards:
`library(tidyverse)`

`flights %>% filter(dest == "BWI" & origin == "EWR") %>% split(f = (.)$carrier)`

Comment: unfortunately it has to be in this order:/